# Creating a Flipbook as overlay only on some pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, header-footer, positioning, fancyhdr

I'm writing a thesis where some images with minor changes are used. This changes would be perfectly visible if it would be possible to overlay one picture over the other and toggle both. So doing it on paper the only way I suggest is a sort of flip book (or even flip page).

I tried the flipbook package but it generates only complete books and I'm not able to specify just single pages.

Another option was the tikzpicture package but I'm not able to manage to force a picture to appear exactly two pages after the first image. This would be necessary since it will be a twoside print.
So for example overlaying a image on the current page would work perfect using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0.cm] at (current page.south east|-1,-10cm) {\includegraphics{Bilder/MathematicalBackground/TracerIm1.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to force the node to be two pages behind the current page?!

So to clarify things, I'd like to have the following:
[image]
I also want to have the images as overlay and not on blank pages.

Any suggestions anyone?! I would very much appreciate any hints or solutions!!

THX
B

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using the [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package; using the conditional on the `page` value you can easily select which image to place on the designated pages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\def\Image{}%
\ifnum\value{page}=3\relax
  \def\Image{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\else
  \ifnum\value{page}=5\relax
    \def\Image{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
  \fi
\fi%    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] at 
    (current page.south east)   
    {\Image};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with the `everypage` package.  I have set up the macro `\flippage`, which will place an image in the lower right corner on the page it is invoked from.  As it is set up, the image should be in a file named `file<\thepage>.jpg`.

The values of `\Hoffset` and `\Voffset`, as defined here , are the distances from the upper right of the text block to the lower left of the image.

To change from the demo version to the usage version, comment out the `\fbox` and the `[demo]`, and uncomment the `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\Hoffset
\newlength\Voffset
\Hoffset 1.5cm
\Voffset \dimexpr-\textheight-4.07cm\relax
\def\flippage{%
\AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}%
  \hspace{\textwidth}\hspace{\Hoffset}%
  \raisebox{\Voffset-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin}{%
% COMMENT OUT THE NEXT LINE
  \fbox{\rule{0cm}{3cm}\raisebox{1.3cm}{\makebox[3cm]{file\thepage.jpg}}}%
% UNCOMMENT THIS LINE
%  \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=3cm]{file\thepage.jpg}%
}}}}
\begin{document}
\flippage
\lipsum[1-11]
\flippage
\lipsum[12-18]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very cool!! Thanks both of you for the fast answers! Gonzales approach worked fine. As I'd like to not hardcode the page where to put the images I modified it according the following:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcounter{TracerImPageCounter} %required to set both images 2 pages apart and is set at the corresponding page

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\def\Image{}%
\ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{fig:CorrelationExp} \relax
  \def\Image{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Bilder/MathematicalBackgroun/TracerIm1.png}}
\else
  \ifnum\value{page}=\value{TracerImPageCounter} \relax
    \def\Image{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Bilder/MathematicalBackground/TracerIm2.png}}
  \fi
\fi%    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] at 
(current page.south east)   
{\Image};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

and set the countervalue of TracerImPageCounter at the corresponding page using:

```
\setcounter{TracerImPageCounter}{\value{page}}
\addtocounter{TracerImPageCounter}{2} %add 2 to the counter
```

Very interesting is that the whole procedure works fine for adding the value 2 to the counter but not displaying the second image if another number is entered!
Any suggestions?

Anyway, helped me a lot!! Thank you very much!!